# How to change final result of loop as a data frame

Tags: r

```
 x1=c(55,60,75,80)
 x2=c(30,20,15,23)
 x3=c(4,3,2,6)
 x=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
```

From this function :

```
NAins=function(x,alpha=0.3){
   x.n=NULL
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
   S= sort(x[,i], decreasing=TRUE)
   N= S[ceiling(alpha*nrow(x))]
   x.n= ifelse(x[,i]>N, NA, x[,i])
 print(x.n) }
 }
```

How to save the final result as adataframe look like the original dataset ?however I used `data.frame(x.nmar)` .
and How to get the result out of the loop ?.

Comment: If you want to this the loop way, you will need to predefine a matrix or a data frame and then fill it up. After the loop ends, you will need to `return` it because all the variables you've created within the function will be removed. `print` isn't being saved anywhere neither. Also, running `ceiling(alpha*nrow(x))` in a loop doesn't make sense as it always stays the same. Neither the `ifelse` is needed if you only have a single alternative each time.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, before the loop I created empty data frame with the same length of original data but it dose not make any sense  .

Comment: Because you haven't predefined anything. You just assigned `NULL` to it an override it every time. I'll post an answer to show you how you should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting the comment to answer*

If you want to achieve this the loop way, you will need to predefine a matrix or a data frame and then fill it up (In your case you can just use your original `x` `data.frame` because the function will not update the original data set in the global environment). After the loop ends, you will need to return it because all the variables you've created within the function will be removed. `print` isn't being saved anywhere neither. Also, running `ceiling(alpha*nrow(x))` in a loop doesn't make sense as it always stays the same. Neither the `ifelse` is needed if you only have a single alternative each time. See below

```
NAins=function(x, alpha = 0.3){
  N <- ceiling(alpha * nrow(x)) ## Run this only once (take out of the loop)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
    S <- sort(x[, i], decreasing = TRUE)
    x[x[, i] > S[N], i] <- NA # don't use `ifelse`, you only inserting one value
  }
  x # return the result after the loop ends
}
```

Test

```
NAins(x)
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1 55 NA  4
# 2 60 20  3
# 3 75 15  2
# 4 NA 23 NA
```

Comment: David Arenburg   ,  thank you so much for your advice  but just change `x.n # return the result afterwords ` to `x `  to give you result .

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `lapply` here to avoid side effect of the `for-loop`:

```
NAins <- function(x,alpha=0.3){
  Nr <- nrow(x)
  lapply(x,function(col){
    S <- sort(col, decreasing=TRUE)
    N <- S[ceiling(alpha*Nr)]
    ifelse(col>N, NA, col)
  })
```

Then you can coerce the result to a  `data.frame`:

```
 as.data.frame(NAins(dx))
```